# Cannot display all items in foreach loop(Stack) in Java

Tags: java, foreach, stack

I want to display all items in a stack but it doesn't work.

Here is my Classes:

```
public class CommandFactory
{
    public Command getCommand(String type)
    {
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        {
            return new CreateDVD();
        }
        //......Other commands
  }  
  return null;
}

public interface DVD
{
     int getDvdID();
     String getTitle();
     int getLength();
     int getNumAvailable();
     void setNumAvailable(int numAvailable);
     String toString();
} 

public class Movie implements DVD
{
    private int dvdID;
    private String title;
    private int length;
    private int numAvailable;
    private String director;

    public Movie(int dvdID, String title, int length, int numAvailable, String director)
    {
      //Constructor
    }

    public int getDvdID() { return dvdID; }

    //...getters and setters

    public String toString() 
    {
        return String.format("DVD Information\nID: %d\nTitle: %s\nLength: %d mins\nNumber of available copies: %d\nDirector: %s", dvdID, title, length, numAvailable, director);
    }
}

public class CreateDVD implements Command
{
    public Stack<DVD> dvdStack = new Stack<>();
    private Stack<DVD> dvdUndoStack = new Stack<>();
    private DVD dvd;
    private DVDFactory dvdFactory = new DVDFactory();
    private Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void execute()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter DVD type (mo=movie/mv=MV)");
        String type = kb.next();
        dvd = dvdFactory.getDVD(type);
        dvdStack.push(dvd);
    }
    //other methods 
}
```

The implementation below will only show the last item in the stack.

```
public class DVDHandler
{
        Stack<Command> unDoCommandStack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Command> reDoCommandStack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<DVD> dvdStack = new Stack<>();
        CommandFactory commandFactory = new CommandFactory();
        boolean exit = false;

        public void run()
        {
            .
            .
            .
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = kb.next();
            Command command = commandFactory.getCommand(input);
            if(command instanceof CreateDVD)
            {
                command.execute();
                dvdStack = ((CreateDVD) command).getDvdStack();
                unDoCommandStack.push(command);
            }

            .
            .
            .

            else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter ID(enter a to show all): ");
                String input1 = kb.next();

                if(input1.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
                {
                    for (DVD dvd:dvdStack)
                    {
                        System.out.println(dvd.toString());
                    }
                }

            }
         }
}
```

I have tried to print out the dvdStack and there are multiple items there. I don't why it doesn't work.

And then, I implemented it by using ArrayList below:

```
ArrayList<DVD> dvdArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
.
if(command instanceof CreateDVD)
{
    command.execute();
    dvdArrayList.add( (CreateDVD) command.getDvd() )
    unDoCommandStack.push(command);
}
.
.
.
System.out.println("Enter ID(enter a to show all): ");
String input1 = kb.next();

if(input1.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
{
    for (DVD dvd:dvdArrayList)
    {
        System.out.println(dvd.toString());
    }
}
```

This implementation works for displaying all items. However, I have been told to use stack.

Could someone help me to display all items in stack, please?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. We don't know which classes you're using, how you're using them, etc. *Complete* means that we should be able to copy the code, paste it in our IDE, and run it. *Minimal* means that it should contain the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you enter "c", a new `CreateDVD` command is created, which has an empty stack.

Then it's executed, which adds a single DVD to its stack.

Then the `DVDHandler`'s stack is replaced by the stack of the `CreateDVD` command:

```
dvdStack = ((CreateDVD) command).getDvdStack();
```

So it's not surprising to only find one DVD in the stack.

Comment: Thank you, I have improved the logic flow in class DVDCorner according to your answer. Now it works!

Answer (score -1):

Next time, please post more code so we can help with the issue more clearly. However, based on what you have here, a likely solution is using a for loop and the stack.elementAt method. For example:

```
 public static void stackAttack (int inter){
    Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(99);
    stack.push(88);
    stack.push(77);
    stack.push(inter);
    for(int n=stack.size(); n>0; n--) {
        System.out.println(stack.elementAt(n-1));
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    stackAttack(69);
}
```

will print out each element of the stack in LIFO order without shrinking it. Hope this helps, and please include more info next time.